# Using Collaborator status of AncestryDNA to see tree owner's shared matches to one of their matches?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com

At AncestryDNA, about two months ago, my sister set me as a Collaborator on her DNA test which is linked to my tree, and I just checked to see that I still have that Collaborator status, and as far as I know that status has been unchanged in between.

My recollection is that up until a week or two ago, when I used her DNA test to <kbd>View All DNA Matches</kbd> and chose one to <kbd>View Match</kbd>, and then the <kbd>Shared Matches</kbd> of that match, what I was shown were the shared matches for my sister to that match.

However, I think this behaviour has changed so that what I am shown is now the shared matches for me to that match of my sister.

This seems to be resulting in many more reports from the above workflow of:

> You have no shared matches with [match_name]

and thus far less useful information.

If the change that I think I have noticed is the correct behaviour, is there any way from my account that I can view the shared matches for my sister to one of her matches?

Comment: This is just a suspicion, but AncestryDNA seems to be having a lot of server problems recently.  These sometimes manifest as the inability to show match details, the inability to show shared matches, and sometimes 400 (page not found) errors.  In the 2nd case, it sometimes shows "service not available", but sometimes "no shared matches".  Are you seeing errors other than just "no shared matches"?

Comment: @cleaverkin perhaps but not frequently - and last night I seemed to be getting less "no shared matches" so this may prove to be non-reproducible.